# Paginating custom post types in category in Wordpress 4.1 yields 404 error

Tags: pagination, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

**Situation**

I am trying to paginate some records in Wordpress 4.1. I have a custom post type (events) and a category called 'training'. I have created a custom category template (category-training.php) which I use to make the query_posts().

I have the following in category-training.php

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'events',
    'cat'               => "20", //(The training category id)
    'paged'             => $paged,
);
query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) :
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?> the_title();<?php
     endwhile;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    global $wp_query;
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) 
    );
endif;
```

**Issue**

When I go to my site at www.site.com/category/training/

I see the first 12 records I expect. The pagination links are below and indicate the correct number of pages. However when I click to go to another page (or manually enter the url) I am taken to a 404 page.

**Further Info**

The crux of the problem seems to be when I set the post type to events. If I take that out and put a ton of regular posts in the training category, the pagination works fine. I also notice that if I then revert to specifying post_type I can sometimes get to page one or two - what I think is happening is that the pages are being set up according to the expected category posts but not including other post_types = so if there was 36 normal posts in the category - I could get to page 3 (at 12 per page) - basically the custom_post type is ignored?

Comment: Get rid of the quotes in your category id

Comment: This doesn't change the outcome unfortunately